# Regexp: последний элемент URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В общем, есть URL вида:
www.site.ru/topic/id (id = любая цифра или набор цифр)
И нужно выдернуть с помощью регекспа этот самый ID. Подскажите, пожалуйста, регулярку) Заранее спасибо.

Comment: THX, помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. диалект не указан, приведу POSIX Basic RegEx:

```
\([0-9]*\)$
```

Соответсвенно, в `\1` будет интересующий вас `id`.

Answer (score 3):

```
www.site.ru/\w+/(\d+)
```

Или проще, без `www.site.ru`.

```
/(\d+)$
```

Comment: Как то проще можно? Без ввода www.site.ru, что бы просто последний после слеша элемент брать в переменную.